# Accessing member variables within a boost::asio::spawned coroutine

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-coroutine

I'm trying to add some async operations deep within an existing codebase, which is being called within a web server implemented using pion (which itself uses boost::asio).

The current code needs to continue operating in contexts where there is no io_service available, so I did the following, where Foo::bar is the main entry point of the existing codebase, and handleRequest is the pion request handler:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        void bar(std::string input, boost::asio::io_service* io = NULL)
        {
            ioService = io;
            if ( io == NULL )
            {
                barCommon(input);
            }
            else
            {
                boost::asio::spawn(*io, boost::bind(&Foo::barAsync, this, input, _1));
            }
        }

        void barAsync(std::string input, boost::asio::yield_context yc)
        {
            barCommon(input, &yc);
        }

        void barCommon(std::string input, boost::asio::yield_context* yieldContext = NULL)
        {
            // Existing code here, with some operations performed async
            // using ioService and yieldContext if they are not NULL.
        }

    private:
        boost::asio::io_service* ioService;
        // Other member variables, which cause a crash when accessed
}

void handleRequest(pion::http::request_ptr request, pion::tcp::connection_ptr connection)
{
    Foo* foo = acquireFooPointer();
    foo->bar(std::string(request->get_content()), &connection->get_io_service());
}
```

This seems to work insofar as it ends up running Foo::barCommon inside a coroutine, but the existing code crashes as soon as it tries to access Foo member variables. What am I missing here?

EDIT: Just to be clear, the pointer acquired in handleRequest is to a heap-allocated Foo object whose lifetime matches that of the server process.